# Export email metadata and reimport in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio, marketingcloudapi

I need to make duplicate copies of a email with some minor changes in it. I was thinking if there's a way I can export the metadata of that email, make the necessary changes and Post it back in MC to create a new email.
Is there any way I can mass create email records in this way? This will reduce our lot of efforts.

Comment: Can you be more specific describing what you mean by "metadata"?

Comment: @LukasLunow I need all the email details to be exported eg: Subject, Body, CTA, ContentBlock etc.
This would help me modify some small details in body or CTA and push it back to MC which will create new email.
Kindoff similar to migrating emails from one system to MC.

Comment: You will need to use the Content Builder API for that: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm

Comment: It's a flakey buggy new thing, but you could try your chance with Package Manager https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&type=5. In my experience, it doesn't work much of the time, but for what you're looking to do, Salesforce says this is the tool for you. Also take a look at Accenture's Dev Tools https://github.com/Accenture/sfmc-devtools

Comment: thanks @Macca 
I tried Package Manager, it does the job, but it also duplicates the email template, images, blocks resulting duplicate content in MC. I am trying to check if I can ask it to use existing content and create new email.

Comment: That'd be back to @LukasLunow's response. GET the email using the Content Builder API, do whatever minor modifications you need to do and then POST back to the API to make a new modified email. The Package Manager and Accenture's offering are just packaging up API functionality. You can roll it yourself.

Comment: @Macca Will ContentBuilder API give me all email details? Like Content Blocks, button blocks etc? And after POST, will it create exact same email in MC ?

Comment: If you retrieve the email asset from the API, it'll either contain the blocks dropped into the email or contain references (ContentBlockByID etc), so if you POST back to create a new email, you'll get a duplicate of the original but not a duplicate of all the referenced assets, like blocks and images etc. You'll need to remove the original id and external key of the email from the JSON before POSTING back.

Comment: @Macca That makes sense. I haven't yet worked on such API things, is there any blog you know which I can refer to for sample code?